# Show value of Js Function without an event

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JS function that calculates and returns a value. I would like to show that value on my HTML page without the need of calling an event. I've tried several ways, neither of them shows the vale, though when I call a document.redy function with an alert that shows the value of my function, the value is shown

Js function

```
function getContWidth() {
                 var width = ($("#content_container_wide").css("width"));
                 return width;
            };
```

HTML call to function (I've tried all this ways, one at a time without success)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    getContWidth();
                    this.getContWidth();
                    document.write.getContWidth();
                    document.getContWidth();
                    this.write.getContWidth();
                </script>
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

There's no command to output the value in the code you provided. Assuming you have HTML element with id *output* where you want to display the value you can go like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#output').text(getContWidth());
});
```

Comment: what does `$(function() {` do? Saw this from time to time. It isn't another function you can call right?

Comment: `document.write` cannot be used there. It may only be used without a `document.open` during the parsing phase, but the `$(function(){})` function fires when the DOM is ready, which happens after parsing is complete. Using `document.write` there will result in unpredictable behavior across different browsers.

Comment: You're right, but my goal was to show him that he needs to output the value somehow, it's not enough to return the value. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @sKopheK I've tried this and it works, the problem now is that the hole page isn't rendered, I only get a blank page with the output value of the function

Comment: I'd suggest to read some JS tutorials, this one might help you with your problem: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_output.asp